# Raiserror severity 16 does not rollbacks trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database running on SQL Server 2008.

I have a trigger in which I raise error with severity 16. When I test the trigger the error appears but the operation is not rolled back, i.e. I have additional row in the table. I can not understand why is that, because severity 16 results in rollback. We also used that convention in other triggers and it terminates trigger and causes rollback.

The table has also another trigger which does not allow deletion of rows.

Here is the trigger:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg
    ON dbo.tbl
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
      IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
      
        IF ((SELECT COUNT(SDS.ID) AS Count0 FROM dbo.tbl SDS WHERE SDS.IsIdleTimeReferred = 0) <> 1) OR 
           ((SELECT MAX(SDS.CreatedDate) FROM dbo.tbl SDS WHERE SDS.IsIdleTimeReferred = 0) <
             (SELECT MAX(SDS.CreatedDate) FROM dbo.tbl SDS WHERE SDS.IsIdleTimeReferred = 1))
        BEGIN
          --IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK
          RAISERROR('Only one record with value IsIdleTimeReferred=0 must exist and it must be the last one', 16, 1);
        END;
    END;
```

When I uncomment `@@TRANCOUNT` the operation behaves correctly.

The table `tbl` consists of 3 columns:

```
[ID], [IsIdleTimeReferred], [CreatedDate]
```

I can not figure out where is the problem. For me code is designed correctly.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I agree that `Severity 16` does not rollback transaction in a trigger. So I implemented the following code (the trigger is `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`):

```
BEGIN
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  RAISERROR('Does not allow modifications in the past', 16, 1);
  RETURN;
END;
```

This code does not rollbacks transaction in a trigger. If I switch rows and first `RAISERROR` and then `ROLLBACK` the changes are not rollbacked.

Why this happening?

Comment: "severity 16 results in rollback" - obviously, it does not, since you have code that demonstrates that is incorrect - so where did you pull that particular fact from?

Comment: I can not tell you exactly where, but as I know severity 16 raises error, which in trigger must lead to rollback. The same level of severity lead to rollback in another trigger. "11-16 - Indicate errors that can be corrected by the user." ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx))

Comment: An severity of 16 might terminate the execution of your transaction but won't rollback the transaction. Add a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` after the `RAISERROR`
`

Comment: Here's an article that may be helpful:  [Clicky!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/05/11/errors-raised-with-severity-level-16-may-cause-transactions-into-doomed-state.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure that the other trigger doesn't have e.g. `TRY`/`CATCH` blocks with an explicit `ROLLBACK` in the `CATCH`?

Comment: To add to @Damien's suggestion, could the other trigger have SET XACT_ABORT ON?  Pretty sure that setting will result in an error rolling back the txn.

Comment: Yes, obviously `RAISEERROR` severity 16 does not causes the trigger to stop operation. I tried several scenarious and it looks like only manual rollback works as intended (using `ROLLBACK`). `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is at no use in this case. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure that `transaction` is `roll back` always try to use explicit 'ROLLBACK' (see comments of [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever), [JodyT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737862/jodyt) and [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751573/andrew)). All credits to them.
[Kevin-Suchlicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149023/kevin-suchlicki) is also right but in my case I don't want to use `SET XACT_ABORT ON`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `RAISERROR`, which does not respect `XACT_ABORT`, use `THROW` instead.
**This is valid from SQL Server 2012 onwards, which by now everyone should have upgraded.**

Because `XACT_ABORT` is on by default in triggers, the transaction is automatically rolled back. There is no need, nor should you, explicitly rollback.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg
ON dbo.tbl
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.tbl notIdle
    WHERE notIdle.IsIdleTimeReferred = 0
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1
      AND MAX(idle.CreatedDate) > (
        SELECT MAX(idle.CreatedDate)
        FROM dbo.tbl idle
        WHERE idle.IsIdleTimeReferred = 1
      )
)
BEGIN
    THROW 50001, 'Only one record with value IsIdleTimeReferred=0 must exist and it must be the last one', 1;
END;
```

Note also the simplification of the checks, and the use of `SET NOCOUNT`.

---

However, in this particular case, you can enforce part of this with a constraint. A conditional unique constraint can be enforced with a filtered index

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_OneIdle ON dbo.tbl (IsIdleTimeReferred) WHERE (IsIdleTimeReferred = 0);
```

This doesn't help you for your other constraint though.